# how to use auto commands in nvim to process files that have a certain name

Tags: neovim

I am new to `nvim` and a bit confused with how augroup/autocommand is supposed to work.

So, I am trying to get the following to work (from: https://ianfinlayson.net/posts/10-mutt)

```
" command on all mutt files to remove
augroup autocom
    autocmd!
    " executes my command on quit
     autocmd VimLeave /tmp/mutt-* !/home/finlayson/bin/email-process %
augroup END
```

It works well with vim (but putting it on my `.vimrc`) I am trying to modify it to use with `nvim`. However, I am confused with how to translate it for `nvim`. I read the documentation on https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html#autocmd-groups but got very confused, and was hoping for some suggestions, since this  is the first time I have tried to do this in `nvim`, being new to nvim.

Update following more suggestions: I updated my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` with the following:

```
:lua << EOF

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('VimLeave', {
  group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('autocom', { clear = true }),
  pattern = '/tmp/mutt-*',
  callback = function()
    local filename = vim.fn.expand('%:p')
    vim.fn.system('/home/finlayson/bin/email-process ' .. filename)
  end,
})
EOF
```

There is no error while going into edit mode for a mutt message, except when I quit the `nvim` editor and the script is executed when I get:

`Error running "/usr/bin/nvim '/tmp/mutt-localhost-1000-234729-13900684134588740365'"!`

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

`vim.cmd` is for Vim script commands (`:help vim.cmd()`).
`vim.fn` is for Vim functions (`:help vim.fn`).

With the latter you can use the function `system` (`:help system()`) to run shell commands. So you probably want something like:

```lua
vim.fn.system({ "/home/finlayson/bin/email-process", filename })
```

Comment: Sorry, but I get an error: `Error running "/usr/bin/nvim '/tmp/mutt-localhost-1000-234729-13900684134588740365'"!` Exact syntax used updated above.

Answer (score 0):

You could create Neovim auto-command in Lua with [vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#api-autocmd) function and use pattern to select your files.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('VimLeave', {
  group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('autocom', { clear = true }),
  pattern = '/tmp/mutt-*',
  callback = function()
    local filename = vim.fn.expand('%:p')
    vim.fn.system('/home/finlayson/bin/email-process ' .. filename)
  end,
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget a pair of bracket in my code => fixed via edition.

Comment: Sorry @lcheylus but I get a different error now: updated with error statement.  I do not understand the error at all. There seem to be two arguments so why the complaint? Is there some other syntax that is incorrect? Updates with more details.

Comment: Creating a new file called `.config/nvim/lua/init.lua`  and placing the above in it gets rid of the errors, but does not do anything. Is it allowed to have both a  `.config/nvim/init.vim` as well as a `.config/nvim/lua/init.lua` file? Is there needed a specific way to call the `.config/nvim/lua/init.lua` file?

Comment: I found that to include the `init.lua`, I have to do the following in my `.config/nvim/init.vim` include: `"source $HOME/.config/nvim/lua/init.lua` which brings the error back, and points to the possibility that there may be something amiss in the code of @lcheylus.

Comment: Sorry @user3236841, I forgot the second argument for `nvim_create_augroup` in my code => fixed via edit.

Comment: Thanks @lcheylus, the error goes away and everything loads all right, but the function does not actually do anything. I am very confused as to why it does not work. Updated above.